# insert blob into sqlite 3 with C

Tags: c, sqlite, insert, blob

So I'm trying to save onto a database a blob but it doesn't insert anything.
I checked the return errors and I always get "error 0: not an error"

I'm using the sqlite3.org example for blob management: https://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=BlobExample

Anyway here is the exact code, maybe I'm forgetting something.

```
int Database::insertToDatabase(
const int zKey,              /*Id of row */
const unsigned char *zBlob,    /* Pointer to blob of data */
int nBlob,                     /* Length of data pointed to by zBlob */
){
char zSql[kMaxSqlFunctionSize];
snprintf(zSql, kMaxSqlFunctionSize, "INSERT INTO RECTS(ID,DATA)VALUES(%d,?)",zKey);
sqlite3_stmt *pStmt;
int rc;

do {
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, zSql, -1, &pStmt, NULL);
if( rc!=SQLITE_OK ){
  return rc;
}
sqlite3_bind_blob(pStmt, 1, zBlob, nBlob, SQLITE_STATIC);
rc = sqlite3_step(pStmt);
assert( rc!=SQLITE_ROW );

rc = sqlite3_finalize(pStmt);

} while( rc==SQLITE_SCHEMA );

return rc;
}
```

I use sqlite_open_v2 to open the database and the tables are created correctly (checked with sqlite studio), but idk why I can't get this insert to work.
(the data I'm trying to insert isn't more than 1k).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, can you please double check if you have to call commit explicitly? That could be a problem, if the default is not to call commit.

Comment: @KrassiEm I tried to call the commit but it returned that no transaction is active so I assume the step and finalize functions already call commit or something like that.

Comment: Hi Pablo, it looks like you have a problem here. sqlite3_stmt *pStmt; and then you call the function rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, zSql, -1, &pStmt, NULL);
Instead, can you try with a variable declaration like that: sqlite3_stmt pStmt;
and keep the function call the same. With the suggestion I propose, you have to adjust the function calls where you pass the variable pStmt.

Comment: sqlite3_bind_blob(&pStmt, 1, zBlob, nBlob, SQLITE_STATIC);
rc = sqlite3_step(&pStmt); and rc = sqlite3_finalize(&pStmt); at least make a backup of your version and try the tiny adjustments.

Comment: @KrassiEm OP is calling thise functions correctly.

Comment: @KrassiEm Hi, Sqlite requires pStmt to be a pointer because its declared as a **pStmt, but actually don't worry, when I tried adding the commit I had already modified other parts of the code, when I fixed those it ended up working, so thank you! the problem was the commit

Comment: You managed to find some really old obsolete example code that does some unusual things that aren't needed with the `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` interface (and were rarely needed before). There's no need to wrap the prepare/bind/step/finalize code in a loop (maybe just the step to catch busy/locked errors). Your code ends up returning whatever `sqlite3_finalize()` returns, which is `SQLITE_OK` unless an earlier step failed.

Comment: @Shawn I see, I just took as reference what they have on sqlite.org but probably it is pretty old lol, I'll remove the loop then, thanks!